# STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)の％についての質問

Tags: django, amazon-s3

Amazon S3 実装の際に以下のような書き方のコードが散見されました。

```
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
```

これはそれぞれを `%` に代入するということですか？
それともこれをそのまま貼り付けて良いということですか？

Answer (score 0):

S3 は特に関係なくて python の文字列展開記法の１つですね

https://docs.python.org/ja/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting

> format % values (format は文字列) とすると、format 中の % 変換指定は values 中のゼロ個またはそれ以上の要素で置換されます。

[Python で文字列に変数を埋め込む方法あれこれ](https://qiita.com/niwasawa/items/27641b803db31f93b8e6)
このブログのほうがわかりやすいかもですね

Answer (score 0):

以下の書き方はもっと楽だと思います。

```
STATIC_URL = f"https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AWS_LOCATION}/"
```